# Zenject add component dynamically

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-game-engine, zenject

How can you add a component to a gameobject? 
The normal path of

```
GameObject obj = _factory.Create(); // Creates from prefab

HasScore score = obj.AddComponent<HasScore>(); // attach the component
```

The problem is that `HasScore` component is not going through `IoC` hence the dependencies are not injected. My question is how do I add a component? Or how do I make it go through `IoC` ? I couldn't find this in the docs, if anyone does it'll be much appriciated

```
[Inject]
public void Initialize(SomeSignal.Trigger trigger)
{
    _trigger = trigger;
    Debug.Log("[+] Injecting in HasScore...");
}
```

Comment: Really good question - unfortunately I have no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bunny83](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/6612/bunny83.html) in [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1244151/zenject-add-component-dynamically.html#answer-1244294) answered this question. The answer is in the `IInstantiator` interface in Zenject.

```
// Add new component to existing game object and fill in its dependencies
// NOTE: Gameobject here is not a prefab prototype, it is an instance
TContract InstantiateComponent<TContract>(GameObject gameObject)
    where TContract : Component;

TContract InstantiateComponent<TContract>(
    GameObject gameObject, IEnumerable<object> extraArgs)
    where TContract : Component;

Component InstantiateComponent(
    Type componentType, GameObject gameObject);

Component InstantiateComponent(
    Type componentType, GameObject gameObject, IEnumerable<object> extraArgs);

Component InstantiateComponentExplicit(
    Type componentType, GameObject gameObject, List<TypeValuePair> extraArgs);
```

So according to that (Zenject's code is very well explained in the code) If I want to attach my `HasScore` component it'll be as follows (Assuming `Container` is an instance of `DiContainer` injected into the current context:

```
GameObject obj = _factory.Create(); // Creates from prefab

// instantiate and attach the component in once function 
HasScore hasScore = Container.InstantiateComponent<HasScore>(obj);
```